# VSFTPD and anonymous uploads

Tags: permissions, vsftpd, upload

I am very new to Ubuntu and its config. I have created an Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 with web server access and ftp server access. The ftp server needs to be an anonymous access whereby the file location is in the web root of the server. This server is not being published on the internet, only on my local network, where a few users will access ftp as anonymous users, and upload files from their machines to the server. Then this server needs to publish these files as web site contents.

So simply www.myserver.local/ftpcontents

The web server is setup and working. My ftp server is setup and working and I can login as an anonymous user, so no need to enter a username or password. This is all good. I need to upload files to this ftp, and this is where I have problems. I cannot upload files as an anonymous user to the ftp folder. In my vsftpd.conf file I have all the anonymous settings as follows

```
anonymous_enable=Yes 
local_enable=NO (I have tried this with Yes also, but no success in uploading) anon_upload_enable=Yes
anon_mkdir_write_enable=Yes
anon_other_write_enable=Yes 
allow_writeable_chroot=Yes
```

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 .

Comment: total 8
drwxr -xr -x 2 root root 4096 Mar 12 11:31 .
drwxr -xr -x 4 root root 4096 Mar 11 16:39 ..
-rw -r  --r -- 1  root root       0 Mar  12 11:31 newftp.txt